# Class enumerator values cannot be passed as parameters to another class's function

Tags: c++, class, parameters, header, enumerator

In a program I'm making, I'm trying to get a certain class to pass data to another class's function as a parameter. This data happens to be a variable from the first class's member enumerator. But I'm getting a lot of errors. The code below is an example of what I'm trying to do. I've added the errors in the comments above their lines:

**main.cpp:**

```
#include "A.h"

int main(int argc, char* args[]) {
    A a;

    a.callFunctionB();

    return 0;
}
```

**A.h:**

```
#pragma once
#include "B.h"

class B;

class A {
public:
    enum Enumerator {x, y, z};
    void callFunctionB();
private:
    //C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'b'
    //C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed.
    B b;
    Enumerator e = x;
};
```

**A.cpp:**

```
#pragma once
#include "A.h"

void A::callFunctionB() {
    //C2660: 'B::functionB' : function does not take 1 arguments
    b.functionB(e);
}
```

**B.h:**

```
#pragma once
#include "A.h"

class A;

class B {
public:
    //C2653: 'A': is not a class or namespace name
    //C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Enumerator'
    //C2653: 'A' is not a class or namespace name
    void functionB(A::Enumerator e);
};
```

**B.cpp:**

```
#pragma once
#include "B.h"
#include <iostream>

void B::functionB(A::Enumerator e) {
    std::cout << "It worked! Enumerator variable 'x' was passed to function B." << std::endl;
}
```

Why can't I send the variable of one class's member enumerator as a parameter to another class's function?

Comment: I think you have an include problem here. `B.h` includes `A.h` but `A.h` also includes `B.h`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a [circular dependency problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-circular-dependencies-in-c). Your files can include each other all they want, but the

```
#pragma once
```

at the top means that only one sees the other one; not that each sees the other.

---

There are several ways to go here.

One way would be to remove the enumerator of `A` outside the class (possibly to some more private `namespace`). In general, you want your classes to "know as little as possible" about each other in any case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's a good link :) But I'm wondering if I should forget trying to use the enumerator for a parameter in my program. I'm curious about the use of namespaces though: In this example, if the enumerator is needed by both class A and class B functions, where would you put the namespace? The namespace can only be used in files that include the file where it was created, right?

Comment: It really depends on the case, but perhaps you could try with some header file that both classes include. That would break the circular dependency.